# Netezza Set Catalog expectiong 'To' or '=' although is should not

Tags: set, netezza, catalog

I am trying to change databaze in netezza sql - according to official documentation it should be SET CATALOG ;
However I am getting following error that 'TO' or '=' is expected:
[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tVngP.png)
If I list all databases, it's definitely here:
[list all databases](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1q1tQ.png)

Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: Hi. I am reviewing your post. Your question is good, but it is better to enter the image directly, since links may change over time.

Comment: What version of Netezza?